# sys.dm_db_missing_index_stats reports existing index

Tags: sql-server, indexes

I'm confused by the results that I'm getting from sys.dm_db_missing_index_stats ...

The following query returns missing indexes that are actually created on the tables.

select * from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details where database_id = DB_ID('DatabaseName');

Has anyone else seen this issue??

Also, I noticed that the duplicate indexes that exist on the database are showing 0 for usage stats.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug related to this DMV, please see Paul Randal's blog post http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Missing-index-DMVs-bug-that-could-cost-your-sanity.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated that the existing indexes are **identical** in every aspect with the recommendation, and they are enabled?

Comment: yep, pounded my head against this a few times.  indexes are identical in every aspect.  i believe that paul randal's blog post referenced above clears things up.  i actually blindly applied this index based on the recommendation.  i monitor usage stats to ensure that the index supports queries after having deployed.  in this case, this appears to be one that is recommended but not used.